Use One Table To Store Data In Multiple Tables
Using Entity Framework Core with Sqlite, I have a table that stores address data called 'Address'. I wish to use this table in several different tables to store addresses. Currently I have it working for one other table by adding 2 fields directly into the table that reference it:
public int? ClientId { get; set; }
public Client? Client { get; set; }

The problem is this only supports one other table. I was thinking of modifying the Address class to have a list of the BaseModel stored in it as the following:
public List<BaseModel> AddressObjects { get; } = new List<BaseModel>();

In theory this would save me having to add fields for every other table that I want to support in the Address class.
I am wondering what is the best/proper way to fixing this?
My current setup:
Address
public partial class Address: BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string? _unitNum;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyDataErrorInfo]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Street Number is Required")]
    private string _streetNum;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyDataErrorInfo]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Street Name is Required")] 
    private string _streetName;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyDataErrorInfo]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Street Type is Required")]
    private string _streetType;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyDataErrorInfo]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Suburb is Required")]
    public string _suburb;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyDataErrorInfo]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is Required")]
    private string _city;

    public int? ClientId { get; set; }
    public Client? Client { get; set; }
}

Client
public partial class Client : Person
{
    public int Id {  get; set; }    

    public Address BusinessAddress { get; set; } = null;    
}

Supplier
public partial class Supplier : Person
{
    public int Id {  get; set; }    

    public string SupplierType { get; set; }

    public Address ShopAddress { get; set; } = null;    
}


Shift
public partial class Shift : BaseModel
{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public Address ShiftLocation {get; set;}
}

Person
 public abstract partial class Person: BaseModel
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [ObservableProperty]
     [NotifyDataErrorInfo]
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is Required")]
     private string _firstName;

     [ObservableProperty]
     [NotifyDataErrorInfo]
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is Required")]
     private string _lastName;
}


You can use a uni-directional many-to-one model where Supplier, Client, and Shift etc. tables each contain an AddressId. Address does not need a inverse navigation property. You can use a shadow property in each of the entities to avoid exposing an AddressId as well:
public class Supplier : Person
{
    public virtual Address ShopAddress { get; set; }
}

Then in the configuration:
modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>()
   .HasOne(x => x.ShopAddress)
   .WithMany()
   .HasForeignKey("AddressId"); // The FK name in the Supplier table.

The potential issue with this approach is that it is a many-to-1 meaning two or more suppliers can reference the same address, and a supplier and client etc. can reference the same address. Restricting an address to a single row in a given table can be enforced with a unique constraint on the table's AddressId, but it's not a simple matter to enforce an address to not be shared between tables. In that case it is better to use specific address tables or owned entities. (same table as the owner, or a separate address table per owner)
If you do intend to share addresses between owner entities, bi-directional links won't really work unless all entities on the left side are essentially inheriting the same base class using TPH or TPT inheritance in EF. if you want to share address records between suppliers, clients, and such you can, it just requires a little bit of work to query each of the potential owning entities:
var clients = Context.Clients.Where(x => x.AddressId == addressId).ToList();
var suppliers = Context.Suppliers.Where(x => x.AddressId == addressId).ToList();
// ...

If you want to neatly put those all into a single list you can project them to a common descriptive class using .Select(x => new AddressOwner { /* populate common descriptive fields */ }).ToList(); for each and Union() the resulting lists together. If AddressId is indexed these will be fairly fast, low impact queries to run.
Edit: With a TablePerConcrete inheritance schema (ClientAddress vs SupplierAddress each containing the address columns for their respective parent, non-shared) The entities can still share a common IAddress inteface to expose the common properties. When you design an EditAddress UI it's model can be an IAddress, accepting any of the address classes.
To share addresses between client/supplier/etc. then a TablePerType schema would be more applicable. This has a ClientAddress/SupplierAddress, but they each link to an Address table row.
public class Supplier : Person
{
    public virtual SupplierAddress ShopAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    // Address columns
}

public class SupplierAddress : IAddress
{
    [Key]
    public int ShopAddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Supplier> Suppliers { get; } = []; // Optional
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    int IAddress.Id => ShopAddressId;
    string IAddress.AddressType => typeof(SupplierAddress).Name;

    string IAddress.Street
    {
        get => Address.Street;
        set => Address.Street = value;
    }
}

Here EF can be configured to either treat the relationship between the Supplier and SupplierAddress as a many-to-one with, or without a Suppliers collection in Supplier address, or it can alternatively be configured as a 1-to-1 if only one supplier should link to the address. (but other parent types can share the address)
With the TPT inheritance you could have a DbSet of Address, or alternatively just use a common IAddress interface which your UI expects as a model. To get that common interface to work you would need the PK and a type identifier (enum or string, etc.) for each type of address available for binding so you know what to hand off to to update the appropriate row.
The main consideration with a shared address between rows or parents is what should happen when an address is edited as part of one parent. Using a shared reference, editing the address fields would affect any and all parent rows referencing that address. If this isn't the desired behavior then you have to take care to insert a new Address record or associate the parent to a different existing address when editing a parent to reflect a new location.
Edit: The IAddress interface would represent the common address view, so it would look pretty much like the base Address table:
public interface IAddress
{
    int Id { get; } 
    string AddressType { get; } // or could be an Enumeration for Supplier vs. Client, vs. etc.
    string StreetNumber { get; }
    string Street { get; }
    string State { get; }
    string Postcode { get; }
    string Country { get; }
}

Ideally I would recommend using ViewModels to implement the IAddress interface that are populated by the entity structure, but in case you are passing entities to the view and back: Each typed address would extend this interface. If you are using a TPC inheritance where SupplierAddress/ClientAddress etc. each have the address fields as part of them then for the most part the class looks the same:
public class SupplierAddress : IAddress
{
    public int SupplierAddressId { get; set; }
    public string StreetNumber { get; }
    public string Street { get; }
    public string State { get; }
    public string Postcode { get; }
    public string Country { get; }

    int IAddress.Id { get => SupplierAddressId } 
    string IAddress.AddressType { get => typeof(SupplierAddress).Name; } 
}

I use explicit interface implementation for the Id and AddressType since these are only relevant to the view etc. using the IAddress wrapper. Your view's "model" would be of type IAddress so it can be given any of the concrete address objects read "as an" IAddress so the view won't know of the specific SupplierAddressId, it will see "Id" and "AddressType" in addition to the common StreetNumber, Street, etc. Id points to the SupplierAddressId, while AddressType can be sent back to the controller as a parameter or used to tell which controller to call to save a SupplierAddress vs. a ClientAddress.
If using a TPT inheritance model where there is a common Address table as well as a SupplierAddress/ClientAddress linking table then we need to add one property to the IAddress interface:
int AddressId { get; }

This is in addition to the "Id" as we will need to be able to relay the linked Address record ID if we want to support re-associating an SupplierAddress to another existing physical location.
public class SupplierAddress : IAddress
{
    public int SupplierAddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; } = new(); 

    int IAddress.Id { get => SupplierAddressId } 
    string IAddress.AddressType { get => typeof(SupplierAddress).Name; } 

    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    public string StreetNumber 
    { 
        get => Address.StreetNumber; 
        set => Address.StreetNumber = value;
    }
    public string Street 
    { 
        get => Address.Street; 
        set => Address.Street = value;
    }
    public string State 
    { 
        get => Address.State; 
        set => Address.State = value;
    }
    public string Postcode 
    { 
        get => Address.Postcode; 
        set => Address.Postcode = value;
    }
    public string Country 
    { 
        get => Address.Country; 
        set => Address.Country = value;
    }
}

Normally I don't recommend initializing a reference to another entity, but it will be necessary if you pass entities. You will need to be careful when updating a SupplierAddress etc. this way, you cannot simply call DbContext.Update(). Since we could point the SupplierAddress at a new address vs. update the existing address details you will need to handle both of those scenarios. In the case of an insert if you get an AddressId you ignore the address street etc. fields and create a SupplierAddress linked to the AddressId provided. If you get a "0" then create a new SupplierAddress and Address with the provided data. When updating you should always fetch the existing SupplierAddress & Address then base your action on the updated AddressId. For instance:
var existingSupplierAddress = Context.SupplierAddresses
    .Include(x => x.Address)
    .Single(x => x.SupplierAddressId == address.Id);

if (address.AddressId != existingSupplierAddress.Address.AddressId)
{
    var updatedAddress = Context.Addresses
        .Single(x => x.AddressId == address.AddressId);
    existingSupplierAddress.Address = updatedAddress;
}
else
{
    existingSupplierAddress.Address.StreetNumber = address.StreetNumber;
    existingSupplierAddress.Address.Street = address.Street;
    // ...
}
Context.SaveChanges();

A table-per-concrete inheritance will be much simpler & safer to work with since the table-per-type model above means potentially updating address information for more than one parent record.
Edit: I had a look at your code sample and it's close, but I though I'd expand on the different examples of inheritance and make a correction to the answer around TPT. While the database structure for TPT would allow sharing, EF will not allow sharing a base address across different types of Addresses, it expects the base Address to be  the PK and FK as far as relations from other entities. The database would allow a ClientAddress and SupplierAddress table's AddressId PK to both point at a single Address row, but EF isn't happy with this in an inheritance model. (which does make sense because that would be two extended Addresses with the same PK)  So I expanded a model called "MtO" which is a Many-to-One example which replaces the inheritance with a regular Client-ClientAddress-Address relationship. This can support multiple clients sharing an address, or a Client and Supplier sharing an address.
The code snippets are all available on PasteBin along with the test SQL Schema I used for SQL Server Express. (just create a database called "Inheritance" to create the 4 schemas and adjust the DbContext connection strings for your machine name / auth)

Schema: https://pastebin.com/Di2t71Rm
TPC Example: https://pastebin.com/rGYELzcs
TPH Example: https://pastebin.com/Xcfv0408
TPT Example: https://pastebin.com/byVJKmbK
MtO Example: https://pastebin.com/tFv6UQez

With the TPT if we want to link a supplier to the same address as a client we cannot really do this as we cannot tell EF to create a new SupplierAddress but link to the same existing Address. With the MtO approach we can with having the same shared Address table. With the MtO association between the ClientAddress-Address I am instantiating a new Address by default. This is generally not advised when working with reference types but the default behaviour for a new ClientAddress is it will be treated as a new Address. If you want to associate to an existing Address row, that is fine, just set the Address. The catch is  to remember to eager load .ClientAddress and .ClientAddress.Address when reading MtO. With TPT there is no .Address to worry about thanks to the Inheritance.
The use of the IAddress interface would be mainly to enable a single editing page for address details. The view bindings and controller action can use this as the Model, but if passing it back to the controller you should be inspecting the AddressType to either talk to the correct type controller for the address type, or handing off to update the correct concrete address. You won't be able to (and shouldn't) simply try and cast the passed data to a concrete address subclass and call DbContext.Update((ClientAddress)address); Instead, depending slightly on the inheritance mode, once you know you are dealing with a ClientAddress you would use the IAddress.Id (ClientAddressId) to fetch the ClientAddress then copy the values across from the passed in IAddress.  For the TPT/MtO you need to differentiate between "I want to associate this client to a new/different address" vs. "I want to update the client's existing address details" For MtO that means also changing the address details of anyone else pointing at that address.
Hopefully that gives you some ideas and insights into options to get what you want from the relationships.

In my situation it would make things easier if I could re-use addresses to save both time and space in the database. Having to re-add them each time I wanted to use them wouldn't be ideal. Also if I have to split addresses in multiple tables then I would probably need multiple data entry forms for them as well.

The multiple addresses can share a common interface so a single data entry form will work fine. Re-using data rows between different parents can be done with a Table-per-Type inheritance model, but there can be trade-offs to consider such as editing an address will affect all parent rows referencing that same address, which may be intentional or accidental.

I am a little bit confused as to what the IAddress interface class for this would look like

"A table-per-concrete inheritance will be much simpler & safer to work with since the table-per-type model above means potentially updating address information for more than one parent record."
Currently I am using TPT because it feels neater in the database. I could swap to TPC but I do want it so that if I update an address it should be updated for all those that use that address.

Yes, if that is the desired behavior then TPT is the best option. "simpler & safer", only because it is one join between parent & address instead of two (supplier-supplieraddress-address) and safer in that TPT you need to distinguish between an address correction (applies to all using it) and a change such as moving one parent to a different address. I.e. clients John and Sally live at the same address, then John changes address moving out vs. they both move together.

Ok so with the TPT way. I obviously would need an AddressId and Address in the tables such as Supplier and Client, but what would I put in the Address Table itself if I no longer need tables such as SupplierAddress? The relationship between an Address and the other tables would be one to many.  Ie one address in multiple tables.

With TPT your Supplier would have an AddressId but a SupplierAddress reference/FK. In the SupplierAddress table, AddressId is both the PK and a FK to the Address table. TPC would have just a SupplierAddress with all fields, as well as ClientAddress table with all fields. No shared Address table. TPH has only an Address table with a discriminator for Supplier vs. Client. I don't recommend TPH because it ends up with null-able columns and looser referential integrity.

Ok I've put together the rough code I have atm. Is this sort of right?
https://pastebin.com/35CDcLjp

It's close. I have expanded the answer and provided some pastes with full examples to show the differences between TPC, TPH, TPT, and a Many-to-One relationship, plus a correction about how TPT won't allow the shared address behaviour.

Thanks for the examples Steve, I am working through them now. I have a question though say I need multiple addresses in the one table ie SupplierAddress1, SupplierAddress2 etc in the Supplier table. Would I need a different "SupplierAddress" table for each one or could I just re-use the SupplierAddress table for all of them?

If you want suppliers to have one or more addresses and not be limited to a specific number then the SupplierAddress would be a many-to-many relationship table with SupplierId and AddressId where Supplier has a public ICollection<SupplierAddress> Addresses { get; } = []; declared. Alternatively if you just want a SupplierAddress1 and SupplierAddress2 optional references on a Supplier then you could declare those as 2x FKs to the same SupplierAddress table in the normal TPC/TPT address inheritance structure.

I have a table will need 2 address fields stored in it called Routes. I have written some code using as you suggested 2 foreign keys but I am not sure if its correct.
https://pastebin.com/7YnwxQMa
